# Why is proving $C^{\infty}$ regularity of sub Riemannian geodesics so hard?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, sub-riemannian-geometry

In Montgomery's [A Tour of Subriemannian Geometries, Their Geodesics and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821841653), problem 10.1 in Chapter 10 asks "Is every minimizing geodesic smooth ?".

Can someone explain what are the major difficulties faced in proving the same ? Suggestions for suitable references are also welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason the problem is hard is that we do not have  a good handle on what abnormal (=singular) geodesics can look like.  See the chapter of my book that describes  abnormal geodesics.  Progress is being made in the Carnot case, but it is slow.

I would look at a fairly  recent article 
(EXTREMAL CURVES IN NILPOTENT LIE GROUPS
ENRICO LE DONNE, GIAN PAOLO LEONARDI, ROBERTO MONTI, AND DAVIDE VITTONE; I think in GAFA)  on the Carnot case for state-of-the art stuff, and the first paper by myself and that of
Liu-Sussmann just to get a feel of abnormal geodesics.

It is POSSIBLE the problem can be solved without understanding abnormals - by some direct analysis.  No one has done anything like this: the abnormals always seem to be there, hiding.

Answer (score 2):

According to the MathSciNet, the first general contribution to the solution of the problem is given in the following paper:

**E. Hakavuori, E. Le Donne,** 
[Non-minimality of corners in subriemannian geometry](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00222-016-0661-9).
*Invent. Math.* 206 (2016), no. 3, 693–704. 
([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=867590&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=11&mx-pid=35739715)).

The paper mentioned by Richard Montgomery is:

**E. Le Donne, G. P. Leonardi, R. Monti, D. Vittone,**
[Extremal curves in nilpotent Lie groups](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00039-013-0226-7).
*Geom. Funct. Anal.* 23 (2013), no. 4, 1371–1401. 
([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=867590&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=28&mx-pid=3077915)).

Comment: The Hakavuori-LeDonne 2016 paper is beautifully written and is indeed a major contribution.